# PDO select all fields with 'date' field formattig

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some prepared statement:

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `". $table ."` WHERE id = ?"); 
$statement->execute([$id])
```

I need to rebuild my query to select all fields with date formatting, something like:

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_field, 'M/D/YYYY') FROM `". $table ."` WHERE id = ?");
```

but this solution doesn't work...

P.S I can't select by fields list because it's a dynamic query with different tables and structures.

Comment: How  does it not work? Any error?

Comment: Are you receiving any error?

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%m/%d/%Y') AS DateValue` is that helpful? More formats are available in this [link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php)

Comment: You could instead handle the formatting in application code , according to the locale of the end user. Otherwise, either name the date columns consistently or tap into the information schema

Answer (score 0):

I have been a little remiss:

```
$dbh->prepare("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date , '%d-%m-%Y') AS date FROM `". $table ."` WHERE id = ?");
```